# how can I parse an array of objects in my node.js and mongodb query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In my webservice I was passing array of strings and then I was parsing it like this:

```
var users = req.body.users;

if (users) {
   var user = users.split(',');
   query.$and.push({"device_id": {$nin: user}});
}
```

but now my requirement changed and instead of strings I'm passing array like this:

```
"users": (
{
    "device_id" = "XXX";
    "display_name" = XXX;
    "facebook_username" = XXX;
    username = XXX;
},
{
    "device_id" = "YYY";
    "display_name" = YYY;
    "facebook_username" = YYY;
    username = YYY;
}
)
```

like before - I want to filter out all records that contain given device_ids. How can I modify my code so that it iterates over array (and take into consideration specific fields) instead of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `req.body.users` is an array try the following:

```
var users = req.body.users;
var excludedDeviceIds = [ ];

for(var i in users) {
    excludedDeviceIds.push(users[i]['device_id']);
}

query.$and.push({ 'device_id': { $nin: excludedDeviceIds } });
```

**Edit:**

If your environment supports ES6 you can also try:

```
query.$and.push({ 
    'device_id': { 
        $nin: users.map(user => user['device_id']) 
    } 
});
```

Comment: thank you very much, it's all clear now! Unfortunately I had to rewrite (mostly expand) my functionality and now I face different problem, I set up additional question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41071134/how-can-i-create-my-mongodb-query-based-on-the-input-from-the-user-in-node-js could you take a look? maybe that's sth you would know about, thanks!