# how can I create my mongodb query based on the input from the user in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Currently in my app I store different forum posts. Users can add new messages and create new posts.
Other users - while displaying the content - can filter it so that they will not see the content uploaded by specific users that they blocked earlier.

Each user is represented as a combination of `device_id` and `display_name`.

When users are fetching content, they do a `post` query and include an array of previously blocked users:

```
"blockedUsers": (
{
    "device_id" = "XXX";
    "display_name" = XXX;
},
{
    "device_id" = "YYY";
    "display_name" = YYY;
}
)
```

Currently there's a possibility of adding content with some registered display_name or anonymously.

Right now I support only filtering users with some display_name:

```
if(blockedUsers) {
    var excludedUsernames = [];

    for(var i in blockedUsers) {
         excludedUsernames.push(blockedUsers[i]['display_name']);
    }

    query.$and.push({ 'display_name': { $nin: excludedUsernames } });
}
```

That works fine - when user is registered and has some display_name (that is different than `anonymous`) - I don't care about his device_id, all I care is to block him by his display_name.

But, when some anonymous users has been blocked before:

```
"blockedUsers": (
{
    "device_id" = "XXX";
    "display_name" = "anonymous"; //represents anonymous user
},
{
    "device_id" = "YYY";
    "display_name" = "anonymous"; //represents anonymous user
}
)
```

I need to exclude his posts by `device_id` **and** the `display_name` == `anonymous`. In that case when there's some device_id but contains `display_name` != `anonymous` - I don't want to block that.

I don't know how to update my query so that it covers the requirement from above, could you help me with that? Thanks!

Comment: I think your post hasn't been answered the first time you posted it because it's really hard to follow what you're asking.  For the sake of clarification, using pseudo code, am I correct that what you're trying to solve is a query like:  !((displayName IN arrayOfBlockedNames) OR (displayName == 'anonymous' AND device_id IN arrayOfBlockedDevices)).  Am I correct?

Comment: Paul, yes, you are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood well:

- If user has a banned `device_id`, then block him
- If user has a banned `display_name`, then block him

In that case, it does not really matter if he is `anonymous` or not.

---

```
let excludedUsernames, excludedDevices;

blockedUsers.forEach((e) => {
    excludedUsernames.puhs({ e["display_name"] });
    excludedDevices.push({ e["device_id"] });
});

query.$and.push({ 'display_name' : { $nin: excludedUsernames } });
query.$and.push({ 'device_id'    : { $nin: excludedDevices   } });
```

#### EDIT

```
query.$or.push({
    $and: [
        { 'device_id'    : { $nin: excludedDevices }},
        { 'display_name' : "anonymous" }
    ]
});
query.$or.push({ 'display_name' : { $nin: excludedUsernames } });
```

Comment: yes, almost - one more thing - user can access my app with same device_id, but different display_names. Then I need to block a device_id only when display_name == anonymous.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: thanks for your help! I had to modify the code slightly, now it looks like this: `excludedUsernames.push({display_name:e['display_name']}); excludedDevices.push({device_id:e['device_id']});` (before it was raising an error), however now I'm getting another error in line `query.$or.push({  $and: [...` - it says: `TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;push&#39; of undefined`

Comment: That is because your object `query` has no property `$or`. Where you first initialized it, you must have specified a `$and` property. Change it to `$or`.

Comment: thank you for your help, I found your answer really helpful! Currently I struggle with different problem, maybe you will be able to help me, I posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41212600/how-can-i-rewrite-my-mongoose-query-after-splitting-data-from-one-model-into-two